# PHP using $_GET at sql query returning no results

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sql

I have this php file in which i send a variable called user_email in an url like this:

http://********************/android_connect/get_all_products.php?user_email="m"

through my android app code.

However even if it should return me some data it returns me "No products found" from the else! If i use the test1 query however it returns me the right data! I know that the code is valnurable to SQL Injection but what i have to do to fix it like this?? Please help i really need this!!!!!!!

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

$user_email = $_REQUEST['user_email'];
//echo $user_email;
// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$test = "SELECT *FROM products WHERE user_email= '" . $user_email . "'";


//$test1= "SELECT * FROM products where user_email='m'" ;


//echo $test;
$result = mysql_query($test) or die(mysql_error());


// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
        $product["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
        $product["email"] = $row["email"];
        $product["phone"] = $row["phone"];
        $product["address"] = $row["address"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];
        $product["user_email"] = $row["user_email"];


        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
// success
    $response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `user_email` quoted in the query string? If so, is it also quoted in your database?

Comment: are you sure it is not a exception from your query? i.e. I see that * is next to FORM in $test

Comment: what exactly you mean by quoted cause i did not understand you exactly?

Comment: "Please help i really need this!!!!!!!" If this is urgent for some sort of deployment I'd fix the SQL injection at the same time.

Comment: The mysql_ library has been obsolete for eight years. Use proper MySQL objects in PHP to avoid injection http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/1272-your-mysql-code-sucks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotes around your email in the get request.

```
http://**********/android_connect/get_all_products.php?user_email="m"
                                                                  ^ ^
```

Therefore mysql will be looking for something that matches `"m"` not just `m`.

You should remove the quotes from the URL or strip them out before adding it to your query:

```
$user_email = trim($user_email, '"');
```

At the very least you should escape the query before running it:

```
$test = mysql_real_escape_string($test); 
$result = mysql_query($test) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Can you also explain a simple way to avoid SQL injection to the OP?

Comment: @hexafraction Using proper MySQL objects in PHP http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/1272-your-mysql-code-sucks/

Comment: To the OP, not to me.

Comment: private static String url_all_products = "http://*****************/android_connect/get_all_products.php?user_email=" +MainActivity.user_email+ "";   This is how i send the url from my app

Comment: That url should be fine. Sounds to me like there are no matching emails in the Products table..

Comment: http://***************/android_connect/get_all_products.php?user_email=m    That is the url my app sends! when i use it directly from the browser i seems to work but still i don t get any results to my app!

Answer (score -1):

http://**********/android_connect/get_all_products.php?user_email="m"

echo $user_email; // it is "m"

so, now the SQL is

SELECT * FROM products where user_email='"m"'    // the ", the empty result

remove the "" in url